# Is there any way to get the data types of each column of a csv in java?

Tags: java, csv

I have a csv file for which I need the schema information i.e, the data type to which each column belong to ? There are ways in R and python , but does java have a way to do so ?

Comment: Not exactly what you want, but [Super CSV](http://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/index.html) can parse a CSV file ... and I'm pretty sure you can then map column to a Java type. 
That would mean you know the content type of each column.

Comment: Possible solution here using regex http://stackoverflow.com/a/31931749/1356423

Answer (score 0):

When ms-excel imports data from csv file it analyses the first rows (without header) and proposes column type on import if every non-empty csv-cell of the same column has the same type.

You can do something similar if you try to convert the column string to a number via Long.valueOf().

if you have a java-tool to convert date-string to date (with different date-formats) you can do this, with date, too